# How to get the User's ID when they click "Like" Button on my dynamic url?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

Please forgive my poor English,
My Problem is that i have a article.php?id=xxx ,
and i set the Like Button(facebook socail plugin) on the article.php ,
and i also set the `like_href=http://bikeid.net/20110908/article.php?id=25` ,
the query id will do the SQL query like every
`select * from TABLE_NAME where id=25` ,
every thing is fine and well , 
each article.php has their own like button and count number and content and author ,
but my problem is that 【My Boss wanna know who click the Like Button on particular page】,
I just want to get the user's FB_ID who click the page like http://bikeid.net/20110908/article.php?id=25 , 
if i get the FB_ID , i can use the faceboog graph api to get the user's name ,
but my problem is that【i dont know how to get the User's fb_id who has already clicked the http://bikeid.net/20110908/article.php?id=25】
Please provide me some example or answer , Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get User Email id on clicking FaceBook 'Like' button?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6249204/get-user-email-id-on-clicking-facebook-like-button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way you can get the users id is by prompting them to authenticate with your application.  The like button alone will not provide you with this info.

Comment: I'll second this: the only information you can obtain when a *Like* button is pressed is the URL that was pressed, you can not (currently) get any user-specific information.